# pytest overrides existing warning filters

Tags: python, pytest, warnings

It seems that ignoring warnings using `warnings.filterwarnings` is not respected by `pytest`. For example:

```
$ cat test.py
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning)


def test_warnings_filter():
    warnings.warn("This is a warning", category=UserWarning)
```

When I run this I expect that my explicitly ignored warning will by ignored by `pytest`. Instead I get this:

```
$ pytest test.py
=============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.8, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/aldcroft/tmp/pytest
plugins: anyio-3.6.2
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                  

test.py .                                                                                                                                                                   [100%]

================================================================================ warnings summary =================================================================================
test.py::test_warnings_filter
  /Users/aldcroft/tmp/pytest/test.py:7: UserWarning: This is a warning
    warnings.warn("This is a warning", category=UserWarning)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
========================================================================== 1 passed, 1 warning in 0.01s ===========================================================================
```

I know about `pytest.ini` config file and the `-W` flag and `@pytest.mark.filterwarnings`, but these don't work well
for my use case of integration testing a large number of installed packages via `<pkg_name>.test()`, where there
are at least a dozen 3rd party warnings that need to be ignored for a clean output.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Have you established that it’s really pytest overriding your filter and not some third party package you are relying on? I had a similar issue testing a qgis plugin and figured out that qgis was overriding the warning filter.

Comment: @couteau - the code example does not import any 3rd party packages and should reproduce the issue for you. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @TomAldcroft Oh hi, you had the same question I do :)

Answer (score 1):

#### "why does pytest ignore existing filters"

This is likely due to [pytest's built-in plugin for capturing warnings](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html):

> Starting from version 3.1, pytest now automatically catches warnings during test execution and displays them at the end of the session

#### How to ignore 3rd party warnings when running pytest

Consider in-python `warnings.filterwarnings()` to be *application* warning configuration, which pytest is going to "ignore" so that *test* warning configurations can be made independently and with test isolation in mind.

You mentioned `@pytest.mark.filterwarnings`, but pytest also has a top-level `filterwarnings` configuration, e.g. in my `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
filterwarnings = [
    "ignore:::flask_appbuilder",
    "ignore:::flask_sqlalchemy",
    "ignore:::marshmallow_sqlalchemy",
    "ignore:::pydantic",
]
```

I ignore all warnings from each of these 3rd party modules. The warning filter spec and mechanics come from Python core: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters

#### Other options that you probably don't want

`pytest --disable-warnings` -- Disable *all* warnings, even from your code

`pytest -p no:warnings` -- Disable pytest's warning plugin entirely, making your test warning config the same as your application warning config. This might be okay if you only want to silence 3rd party warnings and will never emit warnings of your own. However, you'll likely want to use the warning plugin if you're writing a library and want to warn your users (because you'll want to test that behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You can use @pytest.mark.filterwarnings annotation to ignore warnings from specific test functions or entire test classes.

```
import warnings
import pytest

@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore:warning")
def test_warnings_filter():
    warnings.warn("This is a warning", category=UserWarning)
```

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html#pytest-mark-filterwarnings

Comment: The question is not "how to ignore warnings". The question is "why does pytest ignore existing filters that have been set using the Python warnings.filterwarnings() function?"

Comment: @TomAldcroft It was not clear in your original question, it seemed like you are looking for any solution other than pytest.ini or -W. The answer to your question is in pytest documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html#deprecationwarning-and-pendingdeprecationwarning
"pytest doesn’t follow PEP 506 suggestion of resetting all warning filters because it might break test suites that configure warning filters themselves by calling warnings.simplefilter() (see issue #2430 for an example of that)."

So it won't work with pytest > 3.0.7

Comment: thanks for the clarification and links, that does help in my understanding. Basically what I was looking for is that `pytest` would treat existing warnings from `warnings.simplefilter()` as if they had been specified in `pytest.ini` or `-W`.  

Changing approach and writing a pytest wrapper to provide `-W` args mostly works, but runs into a different issue where I am unable to filter warnings that start with whitespace (either \n or space). Ideas?